# Number of permutations of $X=\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ and $Y=\{y_1, y_2, ... , y_m\}$ where $X$ is finished before $Y$ and $y_1$ occurs after $X$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to calculate all the permutations of m+n objects with some different conditions:

- $X$ is finished before $Y$ and $y_1$ occurs after $X$ And the last $X$ is not $x_1$
- $x_1$ and $y_m$ occurs before $X$ and $Y$ are both emptied or $x_1$ is the last one.

For the first one I made this equation:
$$
Y_1+Y_2+\cdots+Y_n+Y_{n+1}+Y_{n+2}=m-1
$$
$$
\forall i Y_i\geq 0
$$
Where $Y_1,...,Y_{n+1}$ is the space between two $x_i$ and $Y_{n+2}$ is the space after occurrence of $y_m$. If I multiple this by the number of correct permutations, we have:
$$
(n-1)(n-1)!(m-1)!C(m+n,n+1)=(n-1)(n-1)!(m-1)!\frac{(m+n)!}{(n+1)!(m-1)!}=\frac{(n-1)(m+n)!}{n(n+1)}
$$
But I know that since the probability of this permutations is dependent to $m$, this not the correct answer. What am I doing wrong? How can I count these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For the first condition**

There are $(m+n)!$ permutations in total.

For any such combination consider just the $x_i$s and $y_1$. There are $n+1$ equally likely possibilities for the last of these and since we require this to be $y_1$  we divide the total by $n+1$.

Now consider just the $x_i$s. The last one must not be $x_1$ and so we multiply the total by $(n-1)/n$.

Your answer of $\frac{(n-1)(m+n)!}{n(n+1)}$ is therefore correct. The probability you mention is just $\frac{(n-1)}{n(n+1)}$ and does not depend upon $m$ since the arrangement of the $y_i$s other than $y_1$ indeed do not affect this probability.

**For the second condition**

This condition seems to be just that $y_m$ is not the last and so the answer is $(m+n-1)(m+n-1)!$

Comment: The way I see it these two conditions and their compliment statement (switching X with Y and $x_1$ with $y_m$) would give us all the possible permutations, so their summation should add up to 1. the probability I have calculated doesn't satisfy this

Comment: Have you taken into account the fact that these two conditions are not mutually exclusive?

Comment: Well, for the original question I'm trying to solve it is necessary that these two conditions are mutually exclusive but if they're not then I have made a mistake in making these conditions, the original question is this: count the number of wins for each $x_i$. And $x_i$ wins if he is the last $X$ and finishes before $Y$ and vise versa, however, $x_1$ and $y_m$ can also win if they both occur before the upper condition is met (the winner is the last one of them to occur). Now in every permutation someone wins, and this number is equal for each $x_i$ except $x_1$ which wins more.

Comment: Both conditions hold for $x_1,..., x_n,y_m,...,y_1$

Comment: But the sum of these probabilities is not always less than 1